# Problem finding voltage in a circuit with mutual inductance

Tags: circuit-analysis, mutual-inductance

I'm trying to solve an example from Hayt's *Engineering Circuit Analysis*:

> let \$i_1=4i_2= 20\cos(500t-20°) \mathrm{\ mA}\$. Determine \$v_1(0)\$.

[image]

Using \$k=\frac{M}{\sqrt{L_1L_2}}\$, I got \$M=0.6\ \mathrm{H}\$, which is the same value obtained by the authors. Now, if the equation for \$v_1\$ is
$$
v_1(t)=L_1\frac{di_1}{dt}+M\frac{di_2}{dt}
$$

For the values of \$di_1/dt\$ and \$di_2/dt\$ I got,
$$
\frac{di_1}{dt}= -10\sin -20° A
$$
$$
\frac{di_2}{dt}= -40\sin -20° A
$$
There's no problem in \$di_1/dt\$, got the same expression from the book, just a derivative. But for \$di_2/dt\$ I get a different value.

The expression shown in the book for \$v_1(0)\$ is,
$$
v_1(0)=0.4[-10\sin -20°]+0.6[-2.5\sin -20°]=1.881 \ \mathrm{V}
$$

So, the only problem here is that \$2.5\$. And the only place I see that \$2.5\$ could come from is \$L_2=2.5 \ \mathrm{H}\$, but I can't see how or why.

Comment: The current in L1 is 4 times the current in L2, so the magnitude of the current in L2 must be 4 times smaller. 10/4 = 2.5. Not so? So \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t}i_2=\frac14 \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t}i_1\$?

Comment: Your formula for \$k\$ is incorrect. You forgot the square root.

Comment: @Andyaka just a misstype, the value was calculated with the sqrt.

Comment: @jonk thank you. I think that was the problem.

Comment: @ricardovaras_99 I think so, too. I'm glad I may have helped somewhat. And thanks for letting me know your thoughts about this. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> There's no problem in \$di_1/dt\$, got the same expression from the book, just a derivative. But for \$di_2/dt\$ I get a different value.

There does seem to be an error in the solution you posted as

[image]

is given.

so \$di_1/dt = 4 di_2/dt\$ ,  they have it the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

Well, when we know that:

1. $$\text{I}_1\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}\cos\left(\omega
       t+\varphi\right)\tag1$$
2. $$\text{I}_2\left(t\right)=\text{n}\hat{\text{u}}\cos\left(\omega
       t+\varphi\right)\tag2$$

We also know that:

1. $$\text{I}_1'\left(t\right)=-\omega\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega
       t+\varphi\right)\tag3$$
2. $$\text{I}_2'\left(t\right)=-\omega\text{n}\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega
       t+\varphi\right)\tag4$$

And we have:

$$\text{k}=\frac{\text{m}}{\sqrt{\text{L}_1\text{L}_2}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{m}=\text{k}\sqrt{\text{L}_1\text{L}_2}\tag5$$

So, we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{V}_1\left(t\right)&=\text{L}_1\cdot\text{I}_1'\left(t\right)+\text{m}\cdot\text{I}_2'\left(t\right)\\
\\
&=\text{L}_1\left(-\omega\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega
    t+\varphi\right)\right)+\text{k}\sqrt{\text{L}_1\text{L}_2}\cdot\left(-\omega\text{n}\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega
    t+\varphi\right)\right)\\
\\
&=-\omega\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega
 t+\varphi\right)\left(\text{L}_1+\text{n}\text{k}\sqrt{\text{L}_1\text{L}_2}\right)
\end{split}\tag6
\end{equation}

So, when \$t=0\$ we get:

$$\text{V}_1\left(0\right)=-\omega\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\varphi\right)\left(\text{L}_1+\text{n}\text{k}\sqrt{\text{L}_1\text{L}_2}\right)\tag7$$

Comment: The question is 'where did the factor of 2.5 come from`? The OP already has the solution in the desired form.